# More than 4 tab in android

Tags: android, tabs, tabwidget

I need to implement iphone like tab in android. Which means, if there are more than 5 tabs are there the 5th tab text must show "more"? How can I implement this? Is it possible to do so in Android? Please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Check out the ActionBar http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Comment: You should not try to implement such a thing! iOS and Android are very different SO with different UI guidelines that must followed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, it's not possible. You can however implement a scrollbar for the tab widget, so if you have more than a number of tabs and they don't fit the screen, it won't show a 'More' tab, but you can scroll to the rest. For more info about this, check this [link](http://blog.uncommons.org/2011/04/18/scrolling-tabs-in-android/).

Answer (score 1):

I totally agree with @yugidroid but sometimes it's hard to explain this to designer :) So you will need to implement that attitude of tabs by yourself, it is possible though.

You can check out [my repository on github](https://github.com/yayaa/CustomTabsFragment) to have an idea where to begin. You can do it by modifying that actually...

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your activity:

```
tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);
```

After adding this you can have how many tabs you want.